# Making a debounce function stop after a several iterations

Tags: javascript

I have asked a similar question but I feel this is different.

I am looking over a debounce function by David Walsh [here](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function).

Any ideas how to make it stop, automatically, after let's say 3 iterations?

```
/ Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
// be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
// N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
// leading edge, instead of the trailing.
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        }, wait);
        if (immediate && !timeout) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

Comment: Does this mean you only want to debounce the function 3 times and the fourth call should go through no matter what? Or do you want to make a function that can only be called three times?

Comment: Mmmm, it would be better to have control of how many times that function can be called. For example, I am using is on a input field -- where the user types some words, the function waits for one second and than it validates the field -- after that, I want to make the function go throught

Comment: That's what debounce is supposed to do: What for `x` timeunits after the last call to actually execute the function. I don't understand how exactly you want it to be different.